# Ready to use TreePanel like in duolingo?

Tags: css

I'm looking for concept how to do tree panel like in http://duolingo.com/

Comment: i don't see a tree panel on that page

Comment: I mean this chart on main site. I found only http://astuteo.com/slickmap but it's very limited

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is helpful at all or not but if you are using Google Chrome, then I suggest that you right-click the content area of the DuoLingo main page and choose "Inspect Element". This will show you the html layout and some css styles which will hopefully give you a general idea of how they have set up and implemented such a design.

If you are not using Google Chrome, there are plugins available for other browsers such as [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/downloads).

Hope this helps.